# How can people get killed in the mirror dimension?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, doctor-strange

In the mirror dimension in *Doctor Strange*, one cannot affect the real world.

> **Doctor Strange:** The Mirror Dimension. You can't affect the real world in here. Who's laughing now, a$%^ole?
>
> **Kaecilius:** I am.
>
> **MORDO:** Their connection to the Dark Dimension makes them more powerful in the Mirror Dimension. They can't affect the real world, but they can still kill us.

If they can't affect the real world, they cannot kill a person in the real dimension either, because whatever happens in the mirror dimension did not happen really.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When Mordo says this, both Mordo and Doctor Strange are in the Mirror dimension as well. So, if they manage to leave Kaecilius and his group behind and return to the real world, then in theory they are safe which is why as they are running through the city while it's spinning and flipping and generally causing traffic chaos (especially for buses with a certain pensioner on board) they are constantly trying to to use their sling rings to get them back to the real world.

The buildings and people that are seen do not react to those in the mirror dimension, since they are not really in it, but rather in the real world.

Comment: Consider this, Buildings warped and twisted in mirror dimension appear normal to people in real dimension, even if building is in mirror dimension. So a person injured in mirror dimension if brought out of it using sling ring,Should he be injured?

Comment: @ZaidSyedMMd - the mirror dimension is just that: a REFLECTION of the real world. Those buildings and people aren’t IN the mirror dimension, whereas Mordo, Strange, and Kaecilius are.

Comment: @s3raph86 Thanks, this explains things. Any destruction can happen to people and things which are IN mirror dimension, and buildings weren't IN it

Comment: @ZaidSyedMMd, indeed, and s3raph86 cheers for that, i'll try to edit my answer so it makes a bit more sense